# Corrupted XLSX File

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, i was copying some files after work from one partition to another. I then accidentally deleted both partitions due to being really tired. I managed to get my files back using recovery software. However one of the files recovered was an Excel file.

Ms Excel says its corrupted and that i can't open it. Its a really important file for me as it has my work hours all written down in it so i would really like to have it back.

Anyone have any ideas?

I've already tried opening it in openoffice calc but it just comes up in mumbo jumbo language/text.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of Excel you have, but I think this works from 2003 forward:

- Start Excel
- On the File menu, click Open.
- In the Open dialog box, select the file that you want to open.
- Click the arrow on the Open button, and then click Open and Repair.
  [image: List item]
- When you are prompted, click Repair to try to recover your most recent changes.

*Note:* If Excel cannot repair your workbook, click Extract Data instead of Repair.

- If your workbook contains formulas, Excel prompts you to select either Convert to Values or Recover Formulas.
- If you receive the following error message, click Yes.

> The document file name caused a serious error the last time it was opened. Would you like to continue opening it?

- Save your recovered workbook.